# Trying to display XML in html

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am just over my head in this basic XML class and I am scrambling to figure out what I am doing. I have been trying to figure out how to use XSLT display an XML document to look a look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdedM.png

My XML:

```
   <systemMetadata>
          <title>Koha</title>
          <creator>by Katipo Communications</creator>
           <subject>library community, research, information services,public 
           libraries, bibliographic management, distributed library systems, metadata, 
           resource discovery, conferences,lectures, workshops</subject>
          <description>Koha was one of the the first open-source Integrated Library Systems 
         It is used and maintained by the worldwide library community.</description>
          <date>2000</date>
           <type>ILS</type>
           <rights>Open-source</rights>
          <identifier>http://www.koha.org/</identifier>
      </systemMetadata>
   <aboutRecord>
          <recordCreator>Created by Matthew Weidemann</recordCreator>
          <creationDate>on 2018-05-03</creationDate> 
      </aboutRecord>
```

Thank you so much for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Add the xml declaration and games,game tags for each entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>
<games>
<game>
<systemMetadata>
          <title>Koha</title>...
</aboutRecord>
</game>
</games>
```

Then create the catalog xsl sheet like so:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>


    <xsl:for-each select="games/game">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/title"/></h1>
     <h3>by <xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/creator"/></h3>
     <h3><xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/subject"/></h3>
     <p>
     <xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/title"/> <xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/date"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/type"/> <xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/description"/>
     </p>
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="systemMetadata/rights"/></h2>
      <br/>
      <h2><i>Record created by <xsl:value-of select="aboutRecord/recordCreator"/> on 
      <xsl:value-of select="aboutRecord/creationDate"/></i></h2>

   </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```